# Map doesn't insert where expected

Tags: vim

I have this block of text and I want to remove the ", :focus " from the line.

```
describe "#reminder_types", :focus do
end
```

Previously what I'd done is:

```
f,
d2t  " there is a space after the t
```

This is something I do often enough that I thought I'd set up a map. I enter:

```
:nmap ,s 0\|f,\|d2t
```

When I call my map, it deletes text from the start of the line, not from where the comma is. So my line ends up being:

```
 "#reminder_types", :focus do
```

The map does correctly position the cursor on the line if I change the map to:
    0\|f,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all the `\|`, they don't do what you think they do.

```
:nmap ,s 0f,d2t
```

I'm actually not sure what it does but it as if you typed `0\|f,\|d2t` in normal mode which isn't what you want. You just want `0f,d2t` typed in normal mode.

Bar is used to separate commands on the command line, however `nmap` takes everything as a normal mode command and you don't need to separate normal mode commands.